# how to use "not" and "in" in conditional statements in python

Tags: python

```
availableNums=["one","two","three","four","five"]
selectedNumbers=[]
for value in range(0,3):
    selectedNumbers.append(raw_input("Choose a number:"))

if selectedNumbers not in availableNums:
      print("The number "+str(selectedNumbers)+" isn't available/nBut it will be changed to six")
```

When I run this code and it asks for the numbers, I type in the numbers that are available in the list, but it still says that "The number ['one','two','three'] isn't available But it will be changed to six". Why is it doing that?

I think that I have to change the `not` or `in` part but I am not sure.

Comment: Use `int()` to convert the input from string to int.

Comment: @Galen It looks like those are just for emphasis. OP: that's not helpful inside of code blocks, since it looks like it should be a syntax error.

Comment: `selectedNumbers` is a list. You are checking if the whole list is in `availableNums`, not if each number in `selectedNumbers` is in `availableNums`.

Comment: so how do I check each term?

Comment: Don't edit your question to make it a different question; changing from `1, 2, 3...` to `"one", "two", "three"...` is a fairly radical change.

Answer (score 1):

`in` checks membership: `a in b` is true if and only if `a` is a member *contained by* `b`.

Since `availableNums` is a tuple of ints, `selectedNumbers`, which is a list, isn't a member. You seem to be wanting to check whether `selectedNumbers` is a *subset* of `availableNums`.

You can either check each item in a loop:

```
for s in selectedNumbers:
    if s not in availableNums
        ....
```

Or you can convert them to sets, if you're okay with checking all at once and failing completely if *any* of the selected numbers are invalid:

```
if not set(selectedNumbers) < set(availableNums):
    ....
```

Note that `<` here, applied to sets, is the subset operator.

---

Also, as noted in a comment, `raw_input` returns a string, but you're attempting to treat it as an integer. You can use `int()` to parse the input string.

Comment: Thank you that worked! but what if the availableNums was a string not a tuple how would you do that?

Comment: @JohnCycler I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking what to do if you have `availableNums = "some_string"` and you want to check whether the user-entered string `rawNumbers` is comprised of a subset of the letters in `some_string`, or...?

Comment: @JohnCycler Based on your edit, it looks like you've turned `availableNums` into a *list of strings*, not just a *string*. In this case, you obviously won't use `int()` to convert your `raw_input` value into an integer for comparison, but otherwise my answer would remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedNumbers` is a list. You are checking if the whole list is in `availableNums`, not if each number in `selectedNumbers` is in `availableNums`.

It sounds like you want something like:

```
for selectedNumber in selectedNumbers:
    if selectedNumber not in availableNums:
        # selectedNumber from selectedNumbers is not in availableNums
```

Edit: As [hatshepsut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3346095/hatshepsut) pointed out, your code places strings in `selectedNumbers`, not integers. Use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) instead of `raw_input`<sup>1</sup> or convert to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

<sup>1</sup> For Python 2. For Python 3, see [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: Thank you that worked! but what if the availableNums was a string not a tuple how would you do that?

Comment: @JohnCycler A single string representing multiple numbers? One way would be to split the string into string representations of each number and then convert them to ints.

Comment: So now I edited my post by making some changes with the availableNums. Can you please look at that